# Solaris tcp_keepalive_abort_interval

Tags: solaris, tcp, tuning

There is a section in [Solaris reference manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2724/fsvdh/index.html) for **tcp_keepalive_abort_interval**.

However, it doesn't appear in `ndd /dev/tcp \?` listing.

```
# uname -srvmpi
SunOS 5.10 Generic_142909-17 sun4us sparc FJSV,GPUZC-L
# ndd /dev/tcp \? | grep keepalive
tcp_keepalive_interval    (read and write)
```

Do any of you know where is this parameter?

**UPDATE:** It seems I was reading the wrong documentation, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's an OpenSolaris/Solaris 11 parameter, not available in Solaris 10:

```
$ uname -a
SunOS openindiana01 5.11 oi_147 i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris

$ ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_keepalive_abort_interval
480000
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a known documentation mistake: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2724/chapter1-1/index.html

This parameter is only available with SunOS 5.11 based OSes.

```
$ uname -srvmpi 
SunOS 5.11 snv_134 i86pc i386 i86pc
$ ndd /dev/tcp \? | grep keepalive
tcp_keepalive_interval        (read and write)
tcp_keepalive_abort_interval  (read and write)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ipadm/dladm command to show kernel network parameters in solaris 11, ndd command is deprecated.

To show keepalive variable use:

```
ipadm show-prop -p _keepalive_interval tcp
```

To save persistent configuration across reboot:

```
ipadm set-prop -p _keepalive_interval=600000 tcp
```

If you want change it for test purpose, use `-t` key.

[IP parameters naming changes in Oracle Solaris 11](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1450/appendixa-28.html)